# Get images from folder on android device to display in application

Tags: java, android

This might be a duplicate however, I need a way to read images back into an android app I am developing. The images get saved to a custom folder called Venns Road Accident. I have looked at multiple sources however nothing seems to work for me.

This is the code to capture and save the images.

```
public void Pictures (View v)
{
    //Call the camera and get phone date and time
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    //Create the folder for the images to be saved
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Venns Road Accident");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    //Apply the system date and time as the name of the image
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "VCA_" + timeStamp + ".png");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

    //Saving of image and allowing for new image to be captured
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
        Toast.makeText(Pictures.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(Pictures.this, "Image not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Be more specific about what the actual problem is.

Comment: The code you posted is for capturing images, not for reading them. Post the code you have written for reading/displaying images from an app and indicate us where the errors are.

Answer (score 0):

1. Access the local folder by below code-

   ```
   File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Venns Road Accident");
   ```
2. Now get all files by calling listFiles() as below -

   ```
   File[] imgFileArray = myDir.listFiles();
   ```
3. Now you can iterate and populate files.